# Complex numbers with geometry and vectors

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

$ABC$ is triangle, $M$ in the middle of $[BC]$, we create $BAE$ a isosceles right triangle and $CAD$ is Isosceles right triangle.

Also we have $A$ is barycenter for $(B,1)(C,1)(D,2)(E,3)$.

I want to calculate $BAC$ the angle $A$. So I tried to calculate $\arg\left[\dfrac{c}{b}\right]$. But I couldn't complete any hint.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why is the point $M$ mentioned?

Comment: Also, the numbers $1,1,2,3$ are mass values?

Comment: I think it might be used as barycenter for $(B,1)(C,1)$

Comment: Ok, but $M$ wasn't part of the problem statement. I mean, $M$ was your construction, not part of the original problem. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let the origin of the complex plane be at $A\,$, then the given conditions imply:

$$
\begin{cases}
e = -ib \\
d = ic \\
b+c+2d+3e = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Substituting $d,e$ from the first two equations into the third:

$$
b(1-3i)+c(1+2i) = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; \frac{c}{b}=- \frac{1-3i}{1+2i}=1+i
$$